# Create a group in a group in Windows Azure AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

Really straitghforward question: Is it possible to create one or more groups in a group in Windows Azure AD?

The use case: Everytime a new group is created on Outlook Office 365, a group is created at the Windows Azure AD. So far so good. However, the scenario presented to me is that my application could pontentially create hundreds of groups. So in order to make things clean, I thought of create a main group with several sub groups (like directory and sub directories), but I don't seem to find any obvious option to accomplish that.

May I kindly ask for guidance on this, if it's possible or not? If it's possible, how could it be done? If not, is there any intention to implement something alike?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups can be member of Groups by calling:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/$links/members?api-version
```

With the request body containing a URL to your DirectoryObject (in your case, it would be a Group)

```
{
"url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/3eb6055a-baeb-44d4-a1ea-2fee86d8891b"
}
```

Here are the docs: [Azure AD Graph API Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers)